# How to dynamically change values in a Map on text change?

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary

> I want to update my ArrayList which contains the map on text change on 2 edit texts and 1 text view.
>
> This is my code for Text Watcher.

```
  private void calculateAndShow(double wt, double rt, double mk) {
        String w = weightLine.getText().toString();
        wt = Double.parseDouble(w);
        double NetRate = (double) Math.round((rt + mk) * 100.0) / 100.0;
        double Total = (double) Math.round(((NetRate / 10) * wt) * 100.0) / 100.0;

        netRate.setText(NetRate + "");
        itemtotal.setText(Total + "");

        itemselected.put("rate", String.valueOf(rt));
        itemselected.put("makingAmt", String.valueOf(mk));
        itemselected.put("net_rate", String.valueOf(NetRate));
        itemselected.put("itemTotal",String.valueOf(Total));
    }

    private TextWatcher rateTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String rate = rateAmount.getText().toString();
            rt = Double.parseDouble(rate);
            itemselected.put("rate", String.valueOf(rt));
            calculateAndShow(wt, rt, mk);
            rates.add(rate);


        }
    };

    private TextWatcher mkAmountTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String mkAmt = makingAmount.getText().toString();
            mk = Double.parseDouble(mkAmt);
            itemselected.put("makingAmt", String.valueOf(mk));
            calculateAndShow(wt, rt, mk);
            mkCharges.add(mkAmt);

        }
    };

    //Text watcher for sum total of all selected items
    private TextWatcher totalTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            int id = 0;

            id = (int) itemtotal.getTag();
            String itemTot = itemtotal.getText().toString();


            if (id >= 0 && id <= totals.size()) {
                totals.set(id - 1, itemTot);

                double[] doubleList = new double[totals.size()];
                double newsum = 0.0d;
                for (int i = 0; i < totals.size(); ++i) {
                    doubleList[i] = Double.parseDouble(totals.get(i));
                    newsum += (double) Math.round((doubleList[i]) * 100.0) / 100.0;
                }
                textViewSum.setText(((double) Math.round((newsum * (0.02) + newsum) * 100.0) / 100.0) + "");//set total text to sum
                textViewVat.setText(((double) Math.round((newsum * (0.02)) * 100.0) / 100.0) + "");
            }
        }
    };
```

> And this is my map and Array List implementation.I am taking all the values storing them in a map and then storing the map inside a array list.All I want is to update the map values within the array list every time text changes.

```
private ArrayList<Map<String, String>> itemData = new ArrayList<>();


 private Map<String, String> itemselected = new HashMap<>();
private void itemSelectedArray() {
        int index =0;

        if(invEstSwitch.isChecked())
        {
            billType = textViewEstimate.getText().toString();

        }else{
            billType =textViewInvoice.getText().toString();
        }


        itemselected.put("invoiceNo", textViewInvNo.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("cstName", textViewCstName.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("contact", textViewCstph.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("barcode", barCode.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("desc", itemDesc.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("weight", weightLine.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("rate", rateAmount.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("makingAmt", makingAmount.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("net_rate", netRate.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("itemTotal", itemtotal.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("vat", textViewVat.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("sum_total", textViewSum.getText().toString());//d
        itemselected.put("bill_type", billType);//d

        itemData.add(index, itemselected);
        index++;
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to help but I don't fully understand your setup. Why do you have a list of hashmaps? What are the different maps for?

Comment: @Aracurunir I am working on the invoice part of my college project.What I am trying to do is every time the user adds a item its values are stored inside a map.And finally this map is stored inside a Array List which I would use to print the bills and store into my mysql database.

Comment: @Aracurunir do you want me to put up some more code for clarity.

Comment: So you have some text field, where the user inputs rate and amount. While he is typing you want to update the map entry with the current text. Then he presses a button or something to say he is done with this item, and you add the map to the array list. For the next item you want a new map. Is that right?

Comment: @Aracurunir yes thats exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Why not just create the map when the button is pressed instead of always updating it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95868/discussion-between-aracurunir-and-user3295583).

Comment: @Aracurunir I tried doing this but my app crashes with a Null Pointer exception